# How to show number in result box oracle forms?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am making calculator in oracle forms developer 11g

i want to show NUMBER in Result Display Box when button press (Button Label '1')

how to show number in display box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger, obviously.

What isn't that obvious is what *number* you are talking about. Suppose that your "calculator" adds two numbers you enter into two form items. Then you'd use

```
:block.result := :block.number_1 + :block.number_2;
```

**[EDIT]**

Aha; I think I understand what you mean. There are 10 buttons, labeled 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 so you'd want to enter value behind that button into an item.

Option I suggested in a comment works, but - what if you want to enter two, three or more digits number? You'd have to **concatenate** them. That requires 10 WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED triggers, each for one digit.

For example:

```
-- WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED on a button labeled '1'
:block.display_box := :block.display_box || '1';

-- WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED on a button labeled '2'
:block.display_box := :block.display_box || '2';
```

and so forth

Comment: I want to show number in display box when button press

Like Button 1 Press then show 1 in display box

Comment: *Which* number?

Comment: I want to show number in display box when button press

Like Button 1 Press then show 1 in display box

Comment: `:block.display_box := 1;`

Comment: I edited my message, after I finally understood what you're looking for. Have a look, please.

Comment: Thanks Brother Littlefoot

What is the code if i want to display multiple numbers 

Like 1 + 1

Comment: Concatenation, as I've said.

Comment: Thanks worked

How to show result in result box when press button '='

Comment: Using a single item - not that easy, as you'd have to parse expression it contains and then perform calculation (possibly even using dynamic SQL). With two item, that would be simpler - enter first number (into one item), another number (into the second item), press button which represents mathematical operation (+, -, *, /) and display the result.